# is it possible to display an in-memory mesh in Qt Quick 3D in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick3d

It seems we have to use [`Model`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick3d-model.html#geometry-prop)'s `geometry` property, but the only subclass of [`Geometry`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick3d-geometry.html) seems to be `GridGeometry`.

Maybe it is not a (performance-)wise idea to handle this data in QML/JS?

Comment: what are you asking? what did you try so far? what was a problem/unexpected behavior?

Comment: "is it possible to display an in-memory mesh in Qt Quick 3D in QML?"

Comment: yes, it's possible.

Comment: @folibis what's the QML type to use?